# Create react app error when trying to run command npx create react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

I've made sure the latest version of Node is installed, but when I try to run the command to create a react app I keep getting this error:

```bash
moose@LAPTOP-A7687VOU:/mnt/c/pr0$ npx create-react-app blockchain-developer-bootcamp
npx: installed 67 in 16.325s

Creating a new React app in /mnt/c/pr0/blockchain-developer-bootcamp.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /mnt/c/pr0/blockchain-developer-bootcamp/node_modules/@babel/compat-data
npm ERR! dest /mnt/c/pr0/blockchain-developer-bootcamp/node_modules/@babel/.compat-data.DELETE
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/mnt/c/pr0/blockchain-developer-bootcamp/node_modules/@babel/compat-data' -> '/mnt/c/pr0/blockchain-developer-bootcamp/node_modules/@babel/.compat-data.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/moose/.npm/_logs/2022-06-24T04_27_43_419Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... node_modules
Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting blockchain-developer-bootcamp/ from /mnt/c/pr0
Done.
```

Comment: Try `npx create-react-app@latest your-app-name` to make sure CRA is up-to-date

Comment: Got the same error

Comment: okay got it to work, just had to cd back to the root directory and run it and hoila!